# how to build and release app to Azure app services using VSTS

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

[image]I want build and release one dot net app from VSTS to Azure web app .
For this I have added some steps as shown in snap
[image]

apart from this whenever i do build solution, it fails or succeed but artifact is empty (sometimes). Also logs shows error

> D:\a\1\s is empty. No artifacts
>   Build is failed everytime with following two errors.
>   Shall I reinstall Nuget packages? What is value for $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
>   [image]
>   Also please let me know what process should I follow.

Note: Azure app ( free tier plan ). App is developed in VS 2015. Kindly let me know if any information required.

Comment: right click on the project node in the solution explorer pane, and choose 'Publish...'

Comment: What's the app type? Asp.Net or Asp.Net Core?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Comment: No not yet. My objective is to build with VSTS with hosted agent.
But no luck. I tried setting by you but it gives error
1) D:\a\1\s\project_name.sln.metaproj:D:\a\1\s\project_name.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB4057: The target "FileSystemPublish" does not exist in the project.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.>
2) Error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.

Comment: Can you share the detail build log here?

Comment: updated new image shows error which I get on console

Answer (score 1):

You can call dotnet publish command through .Net Core (`Command: publish, Arguments: -c $(BuildConfiguration) -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory), Check Zip Published Projects`) or Command Line step/task to publish your web to artifact directory, then archive the output into a Web Deploy package if you are using Command Line step/task.

More information, you can refer to this article: [Build and deploy your ASP.NET Core app to Azure](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure)

Update:

You are using Asp.Net app, refer to these steps to create a new build definition:

1. Click New button to create build definition
2. Select Asp.Net (Preview) template
3. Configure repository

With this template, you can find that there is MSBuild Arguments: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\`" for Visual Studio Build step/task, which is used to publish web app to web deployment package (zip).

Note: if there is error during the build, the web deployment package won’t be generated, so it can’t find the file to publish for Publish Build Artifacts step/task. You can uncheck the option of Always run.

Comment: Thanks but that is not only case. I need some devops way (CICD) for this.
It is showing some other errors now.
>Error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them. 
>D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'publishartifact'

Comment: @Kunal Is it a asp.net app or asp.net core app? Do you use Hosted Agent or on premise build agent? Share the detail build log here.

Comment: asp.net app using

Comment: @Kunal I updated my answer. If there are errors during the build, provide the detail build log here.